# Store and Retrieve items in an ArrayList using GAE Datastore and Objectify

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to write a query that will allow me to retrieve a datastore Entity's ArrayList so that I can display it on a JSP. I am able to add the Entity to the datastore successfully, and I can see in the dev console that the ArrayList is there as well.

Do I need to embed the ArrayList to make this happen? Once embedded what is the query that will retrieve the list?

The `SharedCorpse` class I'm adding to the datastore.

```
@Entity
public class SharedCorpse extends Corpse {

    @Id Long id;
    @Index long corpseID;


    public SharedCorpse(ArrayList<CorpseLyric> corpseLyrics, long corpseID) {
        super(corpseLyrics);
        this.corpseID = corpseID;
    }

}
```

The `Corpse` class `SharedCorpse` extends (in case it helps)

```
public class Corpse implements Serializable {

    @Index private ArrayList<CorpseLyric> corpseLyrics;

    public Corpse() {
        corpseLyrics = new ArrayList<CorpseLyric>();
    }

    public Corpse(ArrayList<CorpseLyric> corpseLyrics) {
        this.corpseLyrics = corpseLyrics;
    }

    public void addLyricSnippet(CorpseLyric corpseLyric) {
        corpseLyrics.add(corpseLyric);
    }

    public void removeLyricSnippet(CorpseLyric corpseLyric) {
        corpseLyrics.remove(corpseLyric);
    }

    public ArrayList<CorpseLyric> getCorpseLyrics() {
        return corpseLyrics;
    }
}
```

My current query:

`SharedCorpse sharedCorpse = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(SharedCorpse.class).filter("corpseID",sharedID).first().now();`

The JSP code that I'm using to display the items in the ArrayList:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="corpseLyric" items="${sharedCorpse.corpseLyrics}">
        <tr>
            <td>${corpseLyric.snippet}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. If your Corpse has a field of type List, it will be stored and retrieved whole. You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) @Index the field.

Also, you probably do not want to maintain separate `id` and `corpseID` fields. Just use the id and load your entities by key (or use the type().id() shortcut).

You may want to read this: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities

Comment: Thanks. I have read the section on Entities in the wiki, but I'm new enough to Java and the Datastore, that it's hard for me to work it all out. The project I'm working on is the final project for an intro to Java class.

The corpseID is actually something I'm generating to keep track of Corpse objects as they are created. The `corpseID` is also a value that users can share to share their Corpse with others. Would I still be better off not maintaining separate IDs?

Comment: If it's a legitimate unique id that will never change, just use it as the "real" id. There are lots of downsides to maintaining a separate id - read up on eventual consistency.